# unknown symbol kallsyms_lookup_name

Tags: kernel, kernel-module, undefined-symbol

I'm pretty new to module programming, and am slightly above my head, but am trying to learn.

I'm trying to use kallsyms_lookup_name to access the sys_call_table in order to modify syscall handlers. However, when I make and attempt to insert my module I get an error via dmesg, "unknown symbol kallsyms_lookup_name". I've read that kallsyms_lookup_name isn't exported by default in some systems, so I checked my .config file and found that

```
CONFIG_KALLSYMS = y
CONFIG_KALLSYMS_ALL = y 
CONFIG_KALLSYMS_ABSOLUTE_PERCPU  = y
CONFIG_KALLSYMS_BASE_RELATIVE = y
```

Furthermore, I found the kallsyms_lookup_name in my /lib/modules/"kernel-version"/build/Module.symvers file. This would suggest that the symbol is exported. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Do you have a line `MODULE_LISENSE("GPL")` in your module? The symbol `kallsyms_lookup_name` is exported via [EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL macro](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.5.6/source/kernel/kallsyms.c#L177), so only modules which have GPL-compatible lisense may use it.

Comment: I'm also having this error but didn't fix by adding the GPL license

Comment: watch the typo: MODULE_LI*C*ENSE

Comment: FYI. kallsyms_lookup_name() is no longer exported since 0bd476e6c.

Comment: how do you export kallsyms_lookup_name ?

Comment: You don't - there are other workarounds thou, but discussing them is out of scope here.